# Java - Reentrant WriteLock on static methods

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, reentrantlock

How to use `WriteLock` on a `static` method? this is what I have got:

```
m_unitLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
m_unitReadLock = m_unitLock.readLock();
m_unitWriteLock = m_unitLock.writeLock()

static List<unit> units = new ArrayList<Unit>();
...
public static addUnit(){
  m_unitWriteLock.lock(); // can not use this inside a static method
  units.add(unit);
  m_unitWriteLock.unlock();
}
```

Is it the right way to define `m_unitWriteLock` as static? what you recommend for such a situation? tnx.

Comment: Why is the method static?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: because this is going to be called 1000 times with separated objects.

Comment: That's not a good reason for it to be `static`. Maybe you should extract it to another Class which you instantiate.

Comment: then this class would be instantiated many times and I get `too many open files` error.

Comment: Instantiating a class doesn't open a new file.

Comment: Agree in principle.  Encapsulation is a friend to thread safety and designing carefully crafted classes is the best way to achieve this goal.  The use of static members when instance members would also present a viable solution can be expected to make achieving thread safety more complex.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, why not?

If you method is static, the lock must be static as well. 
The question is: Does the method need to be static? But that depends on the problem you are going to solve.